# Python Pandas Dynamically Read Excel Sheet with Multiple Header Rows of Different Column Size

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet that I am trying to read into as a dataframe. The sheet has multiple header rows that each can have varying amount of columns. Some of the columns are similar, but no always. Is there a way I can split the rows into separate dataframes?

The data for example would be:

```
A B C D
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
A B C D E
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
A B C
1 1 1
```

The ideal output would be three separate dataframes which their respective rows and column headers.

Comment: Do you know the number of rows after which to split?

Answer (score 1):

`.read_excel` has `header`, `skiprows` and `skipfooter` arguments that let you do this, provided that you can detect or know ahead of time what row each header is on. With these and `usecols` you can define any "window" on the sheet as your df. Combining multiple windows can then be accomplished with `concat`, `merge`, `append`, and `join`, per usual.